# Why do we need to annotate the Service class with @Transactional in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-transactions

In a spring boot app, we have user-defined repository interface that extends JpaRepository.
JpaRepository in turn is has an implementation class SimpleJpaRepository.
SimpleJPARepository has 2 annotations on it

1. @Transactional
2. @Repository

So we can skip these 2 annotations on our user-defined repository interface that extends JpaRepository.
Then why do we need to explicitly add @Transactional over service class which is also using our user-defined repository object only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of having the Transactional annotation is so that everything in the annotated method occurs within the same unit of work and either everything succeeds or everything fails. Putting Transactional only on each repository means each repository can have its own transaction, and the second one failing doesn't rollback the first one.

You can have nontransactional methods on a service, or every method so annotating a class as a Service doesn't mean spring can assume everything is transactional.

Answer (score 1):

This is a has vs is problem.

An object can be `Transactional`, or have a member object that is `Transactional`.

If the object has a member object that is `Transactional`, it is not automatically `Transactional` itself.

Object A contains Object B which is `Transactional`, that does not make Object A `Transactional`.

Comment: Then how we can conveniently skip @Repository on our Jpa interface but can't skip Transactional annotation on service class?

Comment: You can think of it like this. There are: you want to get to a place. There are two ways to go. One is via a bus where you have to specify at each stop whether to stay in the bus or drop out. Other way is to use a taxi which once you specify the place, can take care of the routes automatically. All our normal repositories are built by us with custom methods so we have to use @Repository to mark them. But extending JpaRepository allows built in methods already. You can see JpaRepository -> CrudRepository already extends from a built in Repository interface and annotated by `@NoRepositoryBean`.